# Take the likes from users of my app and file them into csv

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I need to be able to consolidate all the likes from users that use my Facebook app into an Excel or .csv file. I can have the user authenticate within my Facebook app, but is there a way to see the likes for all users of an app using Open Graph or some other Facebook tool? I'm certain that someone else must have had this problem, and I'm hoping that one of you can help me out!

I've been trying to run FQL queries to bring up likes, but don't have any experience with PHP so it has been miserable so far. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There's no way to retrieve a list of users of your app - you'll need to manually build that as users authorise the app see [this question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10071000/facebook-how-to-get-list-of-all-users-of-my-app) for more information
- Assuming you have permission to access a user's `likes` connection - access `/USER_ID/likes` and parse the response, saving it to a file in accordance with whatever language you're using's syntax (google is your friend here)
- Note that your use of the data is subject to Facebook's [policies](http://developers.facebook.com/policy) and user's consent in accordance with your privacy policy and sharing it with third parties may be illegal (i am not a lawyer, this is not official advice, etc etc)

Comment: If I use /USER_ID/likes, where do I get the USER_ID from? I don't see anywhere on Facebook's dev site that lists the USER_ID's for users of my app.

Comment: Note: I'm trying to cross-reference likes within my own database, so I would basically need a list of all the likes from users of my app. Is this possible?

Comment: See my first bullet point - you can't get a list of your app's users, you need to build a list in your own database

Comment: What would be the purpose of requesting, for example, access to friends_likes or user_likes in my native iOS app if I can't export those likes and compare them? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure about the policy and can't comment definitively on what is or isn't ok which is why i'm saying to check it out -if the data is used to customise the user's experience in your app it's probably fine, if it's used to sell the list to a third party it's almost certainly not, the rest is less clear

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem with that the `application` type does not have a `like` connection.  [Application Object GraphAPI](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/)  This is inconvenient when you are looking to gather data on the users that `like` it.

OR were you talking about the `likes` endpoint of the `user` object?  That you can gather but I dont think it is what you are looking for.  It is shown here [Graph Explorer Example - user's likes](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me?fields=likes)

Comment: I believe I am trying to do the second thing, actually. I'm trying to get ALL of the likes from ALL of the users from my app. Not just what users like what things.